# How to connect an existing phone-line to asterisk server

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

At office I am considering setting up an asterisk server to that we can route calls that come into the office internally so that they reach the correct person and to implement a menu system as well.

I have managed to set up a server so that we can call each other internally however I would like to know how we could connect it to our existing phone line to make and receive calls via that if it is at all possible.

Answer (score 4):

You need what Asterisk calls a [*telephony interface card*](http://www.asterisk.org/products/telephony-interface-cards) ; a  PCI or PCI Express expansion card that connects the server running Asterisk directly to your (legacy) phone line(s).

Depending on your locality you might be able to port you existing landline number to a (current or new) VoIP provider and save yourself the hassle  maintaining the existing landline.

Comment: What settings would you have to have set on the asterisk server? Would you need to designate the phone line it's own extension?

Comment: What you're asking is pretty basic stuff.  I strongly recommend you go to http://www.asteriskdocs.org/ and read it ... start to finish.  It will answer most of the questions you'll have about building out your system.